# How to draw multiple color bars in a bar chart along a Horizontal Line using chart.js

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js, react-chartjs-2, chart.js3

I am making a chart using chart.js in react environment.

If you look at the second image, what if there is 130% along the Horizontal Line? `100` is formed with `gray` and above 100 `green`. I also want to make it in the same format as above.

I've been looking for it for 2 days, but I don't know how to do it

This is my work in progress.

[image]

I want to make it in this format.

[image]

This is my code.

```
import { Bar, Chart } from 'react-chartjs-2';
import annotationPlugin from "chartjs-plugin-annotation";
import "chartjs-plugin-datalabels";
import ChartDataLabels from "chartjs-plugin-datalabels";

Chart.register([annotationPlugin], [ChartDataLabels] );

    let chartColors = {
        yellow: '#F4D068',
        green: '#4CC26F',
        gray: '#EBEBEB'
      };


    const data = {
        labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June'],
        datasets: [
          {
            label: 'My First dataset',
            backgroundColor: [],
            borderColor: '#EBEBEB',
            borderWidth: 1,
            borderRadius: 10,
            data:  [65, 140, 130, 200, 56, 35, 80],
            random: ['Check', 'Out', 'Udemy', 'Course', 'Charjs 3', 'Coming Out', 'Next week'],
        

          },
          
        ],
      };



      let colorChangeValue = 100;
      let dataset = data.datasets[0];
      
      for (let i = 0; i < dataset.data.length; i++) {
          if (dataset.data[i] > colorChangeValue) {
              dataset.backgroundColor[i] = chartColors.green;
              if (dataset.data[i] < 100) {
                dataset.backgroundColor[i] = chartColors.gray;
              }
          }
          if (dataset.data[i] < colorChangeValue) {
            dataset.backgroundColor[i] = chartColors.yellow;
        }
      }


return (
     <Bar
          data={data}
          width={100}
          height={70}
          options={{
         
            scales: {
                x: {
                  stacked: true,
                  grid: {
                    display: false,
                
                  },
               
                },
                y: {
                  stacked: true,
                    grid: {
                       
                    },
                    ticks: {
                        maxTicksLimit: 1
                    }
                }
              },





              plugins: {

                legend: {
                  display: false
                },
                title: {
                  display: true,
                  
                  text: "범례1",
                  padding: {
                    bottom: 30
                  },
                  weight: "bold",
                  color: "#00325c",
                  font: {
                    size: 13
                  },
                  align: "start"
                },


                  datalabels: {
                  display: true,
                  color: "black",
                  anchor: 'end',
                  align: 'top',
                  formatter: function (value) {
                    return "\n" + value + "%";
                  }
                }
              },







              annotations: {
              myHorizontalLine: {
                type: "line",
                scaleID: "y",
                borderWidth: 3,
                borderColor: "#333333",
                value: 100,
                borderDash: [8, 8],
                label: {
                  font: {
                    weight: "normal"
                  },
                  rotation: "auto",
                  enabled: true
                }
              },
              
        
            }



              
          }}
        />
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a second dataset that does nothing but drawing the gray space up to the limit of 100.

```
{
  backgroundColor: '#DDD',
  hoverBackgroundColor: '#DDD',
  data:  [100, 0, 0, 0, 100, 100],
  datalabels: {
    display: false
  }
},
```

Also make sure that only the x-axis has the option `stacked: true`.

Together with this, you'll also need to adjust some other options. A `tooltip.filter` for example will prevent Chart.js from showing a tooltip for the second dataset.

```
tooltip: {
  filter: tooltipItem => !tooltipItem.datasetIndex
},
```

Please take a look at the [**StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-chartjs-2-bar-with-y-limit?file=index.js) with your amended code and see how it works.